# How do I prevent prompts to update to iOS 10

Tags: iphone, software-update, ios

I've got an iPhone 6 that I would like to keep running iOS9 for the purpose of testing iOS applications.  Is there any way to prevent the prompts to install iOS10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer, No.
Apple really, really, really wants you to upgrade.

Longer answer...
You'd need to be able to block the domains

```
appldnld.apple.com
mesu.apple.com
```

on every WiFi access point you meet.

Answer (score 5):

From [this article](https://writekay.github.io/Disable-OTA/):

> iPhone checks whether an update is available through a special XML document at mesu.apple.com. This configuration profile redirects the check to only look for beta updates available for the Apple TV. Since your iPhone is not an Apple TV, the redirected catalog check will make your device “believe” iOS is up-to-date.
>
> The configuration profile is cryptographically signed by Apple (in fact, configuration profile that redirects OTA update catalog through “Internal Settings” will fail to install if it is not), therefore, can be trusted. Other than adding a “Feedback” icon that you can dump into any folder at any time, this configuration profile does not negatively affect your iPhone’s performance or battery life. Don’t worry. It is not possible for your phone to suddenly install tvOS.
>
> Alternatively, you can also block “mesu.apple.com” through your router settings. However, as you connect your devices to Wi-Fi hotspots that you do not have control of, this would be rendered ineffective.

[The profile is available here.](https://hikay.github.io/app/tvos10.mobileconfig)

You should carefully consider the security implications of downloading and installing a profile from the Internet, but you should also be able to open that profile and inspect its contents before proceeding.

Comment: Wow this works! The profile looks like it has an expiry date of `2018-01-31`, and it can't be modified *at all*, otherwise it will not install. No big deal, as I suppose apple will continue to release these in the future.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a proxy.pac file for your internet connection you can easily block  appldnld.apple.com and mesu.apple.com. You could use something like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

if (host =="mesu.apple.com") return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080";
if (host =="appldnld.apple.com") return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080";
else return "DIRECT"; }
```

That also mean you need a publicly available web server to host the .pac file

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use existing ad blocking apps to block your iPhone from checking Apple's server - specially `mesu.apple.com` and `applednld.apple.com`. These apps filters traffic coming in to you iPhone via a dummy VPN or a proxy auto-config file.

[I personally used Weblock on my iPad](https://ngszekiat.com/how-to-stop-ios-update-reminders-without-jailbreaking/). There are other apps such as, Adblock or Adguard Pro, that should do the trick. *Note that Safari content blockers won't work.*

The overall idea is similar to the other answers here, but since it is not applied on your router, only your iPhone is affected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to completely disable these automatic downloads (which, as you know,  consume valuable local storage space and bandwidth, repeatedly and without permission). However, it will unfortunately involve the services of a reputable class action attorney.

Comment: Please use this section to answer the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on which version of iOS 9 you have, you could jailbreak the phone - that will prevent the update notifications from coming up again.

Comment: Just a note, jailbreaking alone won't stop the update notifications, but it would allow you to install a tweak that stops them.

Comment: Jailbreaking would kind of defeat the point of keeping an iOS 9 device around for testing apps, though.

Comment: Fair point re: testing.

Answer (score -2):

Cobblers.

To stop the nagging requests to install the update, do the following.
Go into the Settings app.
Go to General > Storage & iCloud Usage.
Go to Manage Storage (under "Storage" not "iCloud")
Select the downloaded iOS update (i.e. iOS 10) in the list.
Select Delete Update.

Comment: ...then it will just download it again... rinse & repeat.